# Why do PDFs generated with Prawn using the Noto Serif font have missing characters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, unicode, fonts, prawn

I'm trying to generate pdfs in multiple languages with Prawn for a Rails application. I tried using Google's [Noto Fonts](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) but the PDFs I generated with Noto Serif did not have all the characters rendered (most of them were blank). But when I used Droid Serif, the PDF rendered all the characters properly (see images below).

Final PDF using Noto Serif
[image: PDF using Noto Serif]

Final PDF using Droid Serif
[image: PDF with Droid Serif]

If I don't specify a font explicitly to Prawn (i.e. with the default Prawn font, which is probably Helvetica), the PDF is again fine with no missing characters. What is happening when using Noto Serif?

Finally, Noto Serif supports a range of languages, which is why I intended to use it for my application. Are there any other unicode fonts (alternatives) that I can use in PDFs that would cover the same set of languages Noto Serif does?

UPDATE (relevant code for generating the PDF):

```
# ... part of a big function
pdf = Prawn::Document.new

# set the correct font for the language
font = get_font(language)
pdf.font_families.update({font['name'] => {
  :normal => font['regular'],
  :italic => font['italic'],
  :bold => font['bold'],
  :bold_italic => font['bold_italic']
}})
pdf.font font['name'] rescue pdf.font('Helvetica')

# leave the first page empty for the table of contents
pdf.start_new_page

# get content and write to pdf
source_url = 'http://someurl/' + language
book.sections.each do |section|
  url = source_url + section.url + '?raw'
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read, nil, 'utf-8')
  doc.xpath('//body/*').each do |node|
    if node.name == 'h1'
      pdf.font_size = 20
    elsif node.name == 'h3'
      pdf.font_size = 16
      pdf.move_down 10
    else
      pdf.font_size = 12
    end
    pdf.move_down 10
    pdf.text node.content
  end
  pdf.start_new_page
end

# ... some more code that generates table of contents and references

return pdf.render
```

`get_font(language)` for `language = 'en'` returns a map (for Noto Serif) as follows:

```
{
    'name' => 'NotoSerif',
    'path' => Rails.root.join('fonts', 'NotoSerif-unhinted'),
    'regular' => Rails.root.join('fonts', 'NotoSerif-unhinted', 'NotoSerif-Regular.ttf').to_s,
    'bold' => Rails.root.join('fonts', 'NotoSerif-unhinted', 'NotoSerif-Bold.ttf').to_s,
    'italic' => Rails.root.join('fonts', 'NotoSerif-unhinted', 'NotoSerif-Italic.ttf').to_s,
    'bold_italic' => Rails.root.join('fonts', 'NotoSerif-unhinted', 'NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf').to_s
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the document you are trying to create?

Comment: I think you should check the copyright and permissions on Noto fonts in terms of embedding (and subsetting) in PDF. Not all fonts allow these things.

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm facing the same issue using Roboto

Comment: @Maragues No I didn't. I'm using different fonts.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using DejaVu

Answer (score 0):

If someone somehow stumbles upon it.

This error exists because some fonts use advanced TTF features, and older versions of prawn do not have support for it.

Solution is to upgrade to newer Prawn version, or backport fixes from this bug report: https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/972